# Rounding a trapezoidal function

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, functions, analytic-geometry, graphing-functions

I need to round the profile of a trapezoidal wave function.

In case of no rounding, the function $f\left(x\right)$ is defined as:
$$
f\left(x\right)=
  \begin{cases}
    \frac{A}{l_x}\cdot x & 0\leq x<l_x \\
    A & l_x\leq x<T_{high}\\
    -\frac{A}{l_x}\cdot \left(x-T_{high}-l_x\right) & T_{high}\leq x<T_{high}+l_x\\
    0 & T_{high}+l_x\leq x<T
  \end{cases}
$$

It is defined using these four parametes:

- $T$ is the period of such wave.
- $D=\frac{T_{high}}{T}$ is the duty-cycle, where $T_{high}$ is the $x$-length of the $50\%$ highest part.
- $A$ is the amplitude.
- $S=\frac{l_x}{T_{high}}$ the slope factor ($0<S\leq1$), where $l_x=S\cdot \min\left(D,1-D\right)\cdot T$ is the $x$-length of the rising/falling segment. Therefore for $s=1$ the top (or bottom) horizonal segment is zero in the case of $DC\leq0.5$ (or $DC\geq0.5$).

A schematic of such wave is shown in the [following image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7tKsu.png). An example of such function is reported in the [following plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fNbFz.png) for $T=8$, $D=0.25$, $A=5$, $S=0.5$.

I need to expand this function by adding a roundness factor $0\leq R\leq 1$, which makes the rounding of such function using the following rules:

- The rounding is defined with circular arcs having the same radius.
- For $R=0$ the corners are sharp with no roundness, i.e. the function is exactly as defined before.
- For $R=1$ there is no straight rising/falling segment.
- The tangent at the edge of a rounded part is the same of the adjacent straight segment or rounded part (i.e. there are no abrupt variations in the slope).
- The tangent of a rising (or falling) part is always $\geq0$ (or $\leq 0$).
- The horizontal segments at top and bottom are also shrunk as we increase R. If the horizontal segments are shorter than the rising/falling segments, then the amplitude $A$ is decreased during the rounding operation.

A sketch of such rounding operation is reported in [the following image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8MII.png).

Comment: Thank you @JoséCarlosSantos for the link, I have formulated in a better and more detailed way the question: do you think it is fine?

Comment: Yes. I had voted to close it, but now I retracted my vote.

Comment: Could you further clarify what is the desired "maximum roundness" at $R=1$? As of now there are (infinitely) many ways to do this, but most likely only a certain type of spline suits your needs.

Comment: @LeeDavidChungLin I have added a formulation of the rounding. Would that restrict the number of possible ways?

Comment: @LeeDavidChungLin I have further improved the formulation of the rounding. I believe that now there is only one solution. I would be grateful to have your feedback about it.

Comment: OK, so as we increase $R$ we reduce the length of the straight segment in each rising or falling part of the function. What about the segments at top and bottom? Do we keep them the same length (and increase the period of the function) or do the shrink too? What if the horizontal segment on top is shorter than the rising and falling segments, as in your first diagram?

Comment: @DavidK The segments at top and bottom are also shrunk as we increase R. If the horizontal segments on top are shorter than the rising/falling segments, then we would decrease the amplitude A during the rounding operation. If we consider the limit case of the slope where s=1 (i.e. the top horizontal segment is zero), the amplitude is decreased even for small value of R, in order to keep the rounding of both the top and the bottom parts with equal radius.

Comment: Note that in this case there is only one circle which will perform the rounding of both the top rising and falling segments (it can be seen as the two top circles which overlap). Thank you for pointing out this case, I will add it in the main description of the question.